# C# Threads Handling event

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, event-handling

I'm trying to have the threads also handle the pricecutEvent but I cannot get the threads to subscribe to the priceCutEvent. So it is not handled by each thread. The reason I'm doing this is when a priceCutEvent occurs the threads are supposed to "buy" more chickens. But instead it is just handled by the regular "chickenStore" and not by the 5 threads. How do I make it so the threads are actually handling the event?
I tried:

```
ChickenFarm.priceCut += new priceCutEvent(reatilers[i].chickenOnSale);
```

but that does not work. Removed a lot for you.

```
public delegate void priceCutEvent(Int32 pr); //define a delegate
public delegate void orderEvent();

public static void changePrice(Int32 price)
{
    if (price < chickenPrice) //a price cut occured
    {
        if (priceCut != null) //there is at least one subscriber
            priceCut(price); //emit event to subscriber
    }
    chickenPrice = price;
}
public class myApplication
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ChickenFarm chicken = new ChickenFarm();
        multiCellBuffer thisBuffer = new multiCellBuffer();

        /*Alternatively we could use this instead of a regular expression:
        ThreadStart starter = delegate{chicken.farmerFunc(thisBuffer);};
        Thread farmer = new Thread(starter);
        farmer.start(); */
        Thread farmer = new Thread(() => chicken.farmerFunc(thisBuffer));
        farmer.Start();     // Start one farmer thread

        Retailer chickenstore = new Retailer();
        Retailer.orderInNeedOfProcessing += new orderEvent(chicken.processOrder);
        Thread[] retailers = new Thread[5];
        ChickenFarm.priceCut += new priceCutEvent(chickenstore.chickenOnSale);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // Start N retailer threads
        {
            //Thread thread = new Thread(() => ReadCentralOutQueue("test"));
            retailers[i] = new Thread(() => chickenstore.retailerFunc(thisBuffer, chicken));
            retailers[i].Name = (i + 1).ToString();         
            retailers[i].Start();     
        }
    }
}
public void chickenOnSale(Int32 p) // Event handler
{
    // order chickens from chicken farm - send order into queue
    OrderObject myOrder = new OrderObject();
    myOrder.setID(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Order ID: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

    Int64 myRandomCardNo = rng.Next(1000000000);
    Int32 myRandomAmount = rng.Next(0, 100);
    myOrder.setCardNo(myRandomCardNo);
    myOrder.setAmount(myRandomAmount);

    String myOrderString = encoder(myOrder);
    Console.WriteLine("Un-Encrypted Order: {0}", myOrder.toString()); 
    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Order: {0}", myOrderString);
    sendOrder(myBuffer, myOrderString);

    Console.WriteLine("Store {0} chickens are on sale: as low as ${1} each",
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name, p);
}
```

Comment: too much code, could you get rid of some needless code to make it more readable?

Comment: Removed a lot hopefully that helps more.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately events don't work like that. The handlers are always executed by the thread raising the event, not the thread subscribing to the event.

Comment: is there any other kind of way to do this then? The reason being is the assignment calls for when a retailer receives a notification that a new sale is going on, they will order. But the order needs to have a Retailer number. The retailer # in our case will be the thread's ID. But the thread ID will not be equal to the retailers thread if it is being executed by the chickenfarm.

Comment: @user1726225: Practically you're trying to execute a method on a separate thread when another thread raises an event. The way I see it, the only way to do it is by cooperation, i.e. the threads waiting for the event need to voluntarily wait at some point in their code for the event to be signaled and then execute the required code.

Comment: That helped out a lot. Thanks Tudor. I got it to work now. By having it wait for it to be true and then alerting with a flag. Thanks man.